# Facebook access token stays valid after logout?

Tags: facebook, session, access-token

So I'm working on an website that integrates Facebook, and I've come across a weird issue. The thing is, an access token needs to be handled like it could turn invalid at any time. Like for example if a user logs out or changes his/her password, they you'd get OAuthException's at further requests, right?

However, when I log out, it seems the access token my app uses remains valid, which poses a problem since a user needs to log out from our website before they can log in with another facebook account.

Is anyone here experiencing the same problem where the access token remains valid even though the user logs out of facebook? I'm trying to find a creative solution to this problem so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is because facebook integration into a separate site assumes that you don't want a user to be logged out of your separate site when they logout of the facebook site.

Basically there are 2 user 'access_tokens' which can be used; code, and signed_request - signed_request is the one that gets invalidated by facebook once the user logs out, where code stays valid for a period of time.

Only code gets returned from a Login with facebook request, which means the access_token will only invalidate after the time has elapsed.

signed_request gets sent when an app is being called within facebook itself, i.e. a canvass app, this token takes precedence over the 'code' parameter, and this will override a 'code' access_token.

So the app I'm building has both a micro site, separate from facebook, and a facebook canvass app, both pointing to the same host, so if a user logs in through the separate site, then logs out of facebook, their session on my separate site will stay active, and so if another user logs into facebook on the same machine, and they access the separate site, they will see the previous users information because they haven't logged themselves out of my site, but if they were to goto the canvass app from within facebook, facebook would send a 'signed_request' param which would override the separate sites session, and log the appropriate user in, which also means their session would get invalidated when they logout of facebook.

There are only 2 solutions that i see:

1) You could invalidate the stored session at the end of every page, this would then force your site to redirect to facebook login for every page request, which would redirect straight back if the user is already logged in, but at the cost of some performance.

2) Only use the website through facebook, i.e. force the user to use the canvass app.